# Intellij - Productivity Guide

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I couldn't find any answer after a bit of googling. I wonder if anyone knows how Intellij is calculating the time is suppose to save with shortcuts?

I'm talking about this:[image: productivity_guide]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the code completion is executed, the IDE counts the number of characters it inserted for you (e.g. if you typed "pr" and completed to "print", it'd be 3 characters).

As for quick fixes, it just counts how many of them you invoked (by Alt+Enter). Quick fixes are normally issued on inspection warnings, which is a yellow code and usually it's probable bugs that are highlighted in that way.

Comment: Thanks, there was a personal misunderstanding of ~878 per working day. Somehow I read, "it saved you 878 working days" and I was wonder how they were able to calculate such a thing!